# Eliminating $y$ from the system $cx − sy = 2$ and $sx + cy = 1$, where $c=\cos\theta$, $s=\sin\theta$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, systems-of-equations

> We will write $c = \cos\theta$ and $s = \sin\theta$ for ease of notation. Eliminate $y$ from the simultaneous equations
>   $$\begin{align}
> cx − sy = 2 \\
> sx + cy = 1
> \end{align}$$

How could you eliminate $y$ from these equations? I have no idea where to start.

Thank you.
also how does this prove, it is solvable for all values of sin and cos.

Comment: Multiply the first one by $c$ and the second one by $s$, and add them together.

Comment: To be clear: Do you mean that "$cx$" represents "$x \cos\theta$"? or that it represents "$\cos x$"?

Comment: yes, xcostheta.

Comment: $\det\pmatrix{c&-s\\s&c}=c^2+s^2=1$ for all $\theta$, therefore the system is always consistent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiply the first equation by $c$ to obtain: $c^2x-scy=2c$ and the second equation by $s$ to get: $s^2x+scy=s$. Now add the 2 equations term by term to obtain $(c^2+s^2)x=2c+s$. Using the trigonometric identity $\sin(x)^2+\cos(x)^2=1$ and you see that $x=2c+s$. Use then one of the original equations, substitute your value for $x$ and see that, after simplification $y=c-2s$.

$x$ and $y$ are defined $\forall \theta$.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

After eliminating $y$ usual way ( mentioned by A. Goodier in comments ) you get
$$ 2 \cos \theta + \sin \theta  =x $$

To find range for $x:$ differentiate, set to zero and solve

$$ -2  \sin \theta+ \cos \theta =0$$

$\theta=\tan^{-1} \frac12;$ plug this into the expression to evaluate max/min range values, it comes to $ \pm \sqrt 5.$

$x$ must be in the interval $ (\sqrt 5 > x >-\sqrt 5) $ to have a real $ \theta$ angle solution ( that would be periodic).

Comment: I understand that he did not ask for the range of $x$ or $y$, but whether it had a solution for any value of $\theta$, but maybe I got that wrong?

Comment: In the  last line he asks:  if solvable for values of $\theta$ etc.  that to me sounded as if his query is seeking to find what acceptable $x$ value have  a valid $\theta $  solution..

Comment: I see, weil anyway, he now has everything that can be said concerning the question, hasn't he? :)

Comment: Well, :)  the teacher should also  look through a student's mind, right?

Comment: And two teachers are better at it than one....

Comment: Vous avez raison !